# How do I use separate_wider_regex on rgb(1,22,333),

Tags: r

My code does not give me the expected values

| Column A | Red | Green | Blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rgb(111,222,334) | 111 | 222 | 334 |
| rgb(11,22,3) | 11 | 22 | 3 |

Column A is divided to 3 new columns

```
(df_data <- df3|>
     separate_wider_regex(
    cols = Column A,
    patterns = c(red = "rgb\\((\\d+),\\s*\\d+,\\s*\\d+\\)",
             green = "rgb\\(\\d+,\\s*(\\d+),\\s*\\d+\\)",
             blue = "rgb\\(\\d+,\\s*\\d+,\\s*(\\d+)\\)")
```

Data:

```
df_data <- data.frame(ColumnA = c("rgb(111,222,334)", "rgb(11,22,3)"))
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why does your title specifically ask for `separate_wider_regex` but then you accept the answer that doesn't use `separate_wider_regex`? Be sure to accurately describe your question and the requirements in the title and body of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution with `strsplit`.

```r
df_data <- data.frame(ColumnA = c("rgb(111,222,334)", "rgb(11,22,3)"))

strsplit(df_data$ColumnA, "[[:alpha:]]+|\\(|\\)|,") |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    ok <- (x |> trimws() |> nchar()) > 0L
    x[ok] |> as.numeric()
  }) |>
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _) |>
  setNames(c("Red", "Green", "Blue"))
#>   Red Green Blue
#> 1 111   222  334
#> 2  11    22    3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

`patterns` vector of `separate_wider_regex()` should form a match but it can include named and unnamed items, only named patterns will end up in columns:

```r
library(tidyr)

df_data <- data.frame(ColumnA = c("rgb(111,222,334)", "rgb(11,22,3)"))
df_data |> separate_wider_regex(ColumnA, 
                            patterns = c("^rgb\\(", 
                                         red   = "\\d+", ",", 
                                         green = "\\d+", ",", 
                                         blue  = "\\d+", "\\)$"))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   red   green blue 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 111   222   334  
#> 2 11    22    3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a simpler approach than using regex would be to first remove the `rgb(` and `)` using `dplyr::mutate` then use `tidyr::separate_wider_delim`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_data %>% 
  mutate(ColumnA = gsub("rgb\\(|\\)", "", ColumnA)) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(ColumnA, 
                       names = c("Red","Green", "Blue"), 
                       delim = ",")

#   Red   Green Blue 
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 111   222   334  
# 2 11    22    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative base-R methods:

```r
strcapture("(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)", df_data$ColumnA, list(Red=0L, Green=0L, Blue=0L)) |>
  cbind(df_data)
#   Red Green Blue          ColumnA
# 1 111   222  334 rgb(111,222,334)
# 2  11    22    3     rgb(11,22,3)
```

```r
regmatches(df_data$ColumnA, gregexpr("[0-9]+", df_data$ColumnA)) |>
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _) |>
  setNames(c("Red", "Green", "Blue")) |>
  cbind(df_data)
#   Red Green Blue          ColumnA
# 1 111   222  334 rgb(111,222,334)
# 2  11    22    3     rgb(11,22,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another piped base R approach

```r
df_data <- data.frame(ColumnA = c("rgb(111,222,334)", "rgb(11,22,3)"))
strsplit(x = gsub(pattern = "rgb\\(|\\)", x = df_data$ColumnA, replacement = ""), split = ",") |>
  { \(x) data.frame(matrix(unlist(x), ncol = 3L, byrow = TRUE))}() |> 
  { \(x) cbind(df_data$ColumnA, x)}() |>
  `colnames<-`(c("ColumnA", "Red", "Green", "Blue"))
#>            ColumnA Red Green Blue
#> 1 rgb(111,222,334) 111   222  334
#> 2     rgb(11,22,3)  11    22    3
```

using `|> { \(x) ... }()`.

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>